# How to make a Discord bot command that gives users a role?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a command that gives users a role without mentioning them, but I don't know how to do it.

code:

```
@bot.command()
async def blog(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='abbonato-blogger')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send('fatto.')
```

error:

```
PS C:\Users\Fred\Desktop\Cyberpapera2.0> & C:/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/Fred/Desktop/Cyberpapera2.0/bot.py
Ignoring exception in command blog:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Fred/Desktop/Cyberpapera2.0/bot.py", line 632, in blog
    await member.add_roles(role)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Comment: Which user should get the role if the caller doesn't specify one?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh any user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is due to the default value of `member` being `None`.
When the command is invoked with no arguments, e.g. by `!blog`, `member` will be `None`, so when the line, `await member.add_roles(role)` is reached, the `AttributeError` occurs, telling you that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'`.

You should handle your default value case and check for when `member is None`.
Alternatively, if you don't want to process the command when a `member` isn't passed, you can remove the default value entirely and handle the [`MissingRequiredArgument` exception](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument).